3D object not showing in the 3D space - jsartoolkit5
this is my first question, so I hope to do everything as intended.
I'm currently trying to learn a little bit about augmented reality using web apps and I'm trying to do some basic stuff.
I'm trying to create a project with image/marker recognition and a 3d environment always present and visible on the AR.
I'm using the jsartoolkit5 library.
Starting from heir "intro_example.html" I imported the needed assets in a local server to build my own project.
The page works just fine, so if I scan the marker with my phone I can see the 3d cube on it (the animation on the click event won't play, but I don't care right now).
Then I wanted to place another 3d object that is always visible and put in the 3d space so that I could move around with my phone and see the object in AR from every angle.
I tried different things but the object won't show in any case. I'm sure that's a really basic and stupid issue, probably due to my inexperience. Can someone help me please?
That's my html page (as I said I started from their examples and added few lines).
<html>
<head>
<title>Box demo with Three.js</title>
<meta meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<style>
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.portrait canvas {
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
}
.desktop canvas {
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Box demo with Three.js</h1>
<p>On Chrome on Android, tap the screen to start playing video stream.</p>
<p>Show <a href="https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/blob/master/doc/patterns/Matrix%20code%203x3%20(72dpi)/20.png">3x3 marker id 20</a> to camera to display a box on top of it. Tap the box to open it.


<p>&larr; <a href="../index.html">Back</a></p>

<script async src="artoolkit.min.js"></script>
<script async src="three.min.js"></script>
<script async src="artoolkit.three.js"></script>

<script>

var findObjectUnderEvent = function(ev, camera, objects) {

    var style = getComputedStyle(ev.target);
    var elementTransform = style.getPropertyValue('transform');
    var elementTransformOrigin = style.getPropertyValue('transform-origin');

    var xyz = elementTransformOrigin.replace(/px/g, '').split(" ");
    xyz[0] = parseFloat(xyz[0]);
    xyz[1] = parseFloat(xyz[1]);
    xyz[2] = parseFloat(xyz[2] || 0);

    var mat = new THREE.Matrix4();
    mat.identity();
    if (/^matrix\(/.test(elementTransform)) {
        var elems = elementTransform.replace(/^matrix\(|\)$/g, '').split(' ');
        mat.elements[0] = parseFloat(elems[0]);
        mat.elements[1] = parseFloat(elems[1]);
        mat.elements[4] = parseFloat(elems[2]);
        mat.elements[5] = parseFloat(elems[3]);
        mat.elements[12] = parseFloat(elems[4]);
        mat.elements[13] = parseFloat(elems[5]);
    } else if (/^matrix3d\(/i.test(elementTransform)) {
        var elems = elementTransform.replace(/^matrix3d\(|\)$/ig, '').split(' ');
        for (var i=0; i<16; i++) {
            mat.elements[i] = parseFloat(elems[i]);
        }
    }

    var mat2 = new THREE.Matrix4();
    mat2.makeTranslation(xyz[0], xyz[1], xyz[2]);
    mat2.multiply(mat);
    mat.makeTranslation(-xyz[0], -xyz[1], -xyz[2]);
    mat2.multiply(mat);

    var vec = new THREE.Vector3(ev.layerX, ev.layerY, 0);
    vec.applyMatrix4(mat2);

    var width = parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('width'));
    var height = parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('height'));

    var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3(
        ( vec.x / width ) * 2 - 1,
        -( vec.y / height ) * 2 + 1,
        0.5
    );
    mouse3D.unproject( camera );
    mouse3D.sub( camera.position );
    mouse3D.normalize();
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, mouse3D );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        var obj = intersects[ 0 ].object
        return obj;
    }
};


var createBox = function() {
    // The AR scene.
    //
    // The box object is going to be placed on top of the marker in the video.
    // I'm adding it to the markerRoot object and when the markerRoot moves,
    // the box and its children move with it.
    //
    var box = new THREE.Object3D();
    var boxWall = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 0.1, 1, 1, 1),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff})
    );
    boxWall.position.z = -0.5;
    box.add(boxWall);

    boxWall = boxWall.clone();
    boxWall.position.z = +0.5;
    box.add(boxWall);

    boxWall = boxWall.clone();
    boxWall.position.z = 0;
    boxWall.position.x = -0.5;
    boxWall.rotation.y = Math.PI/2;
    box.add(boxWall);

    boxWall = boxWall.clone();
    boxWall.position.x = +0.5;
    box.add(boxWall);

    boxWall = boxWall.clone();
    boxWall.position.x = 0;
    boxWall.position.y = -0.5;
    boxWall.rotation.y = 0;
    boxWall.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
    box.add(boxWall);

    // Keep track of the box walls to test if the mouse clicks happen on top of them.
    var walls = box.children.slice();

    // Create a pivot for the lid of the box to make it rotate around its "hinge".
    var pivot = new THREE.Object3D();
    pivot.position.y = 0.5;
    pivot.position.x = 0.5;

    // The lid of the box is attached to the pivot and the pivot is attached to the box.
    boxWall = boxWall.clone();
    boxWall.position.y = 0;
    boxWall.position.x = -0.5;
    pivot.add(boxWall);
    box.add(pivot);

    walls.push(boxWall);

    box.position.z = 0.5;
    box.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;

    box.open = false;

    box.tick = function() {
        // Animate the box lid to open rotation or closed rotation, depending on the value of the open variable.
        pivot.rotation.z += ((box.open ? -Math.PI/1.5 : 0) - pivot.rotation.z) * 0.1;
    };

    return {box: box, walls: walls};
};


window.ARThreeOnLoad = function() {

    ARController.getUserMediaThreeScene({maxARVideoSize: 320, cameraParam: 'camera_para-iPhone 5 rear 640x480 1.0m.dat',
    onSuccess: function(arScene, arController, arCamera) {

        arController.setPatternDetectionMode(artoolkit.AR_MATRIX_CODE_DETECTION);

        document.body.className = arController.orientation;

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
        if (arController.orientation === 'portrait') {
            var w = (window.innerWidth / arController.videoHeight) * arController.videoWidth;
            var h = window.innerWidth;
            renderer.setSize(w, h);
            renderer.domElement.style.paddingBottom = (w-h) + 'px';
        } else {
            if (/Android|mobile|iPad|iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, (window.innerWidth / arController.videoWidth) * arController.videoHeight);
            } else {
                renderer.setSize(arController.videoWidth, arController.videoHeight);
                document.body.className += ' desktop';
            }
        }

        document.body.insertBefore(renderer.domElement, document.body.firstChild);


        // Create a couple of lights for our AR scene.
        var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(40, 40, 40);
        arScene.scene.add(light);

        var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xff8800);
        light.position.set(-40, -20, -30);
        arScene.scene.add(light);


        //the object fixed in 3d space
        var sphere = new THREE.Object3D();
        var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
                new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 8, 8),
                new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
            );
        sphereMesh.material.flatShading;
        sphere.add(sphereMesh);
        sphere.position.set(5, 5, 5);
        arScene.scene.add(sphere);

        var box = createBox();

        renderer.domElement.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
            if (findObjectUnderEvent(ev, arScene.camera, box.walls)) {
                box.box.open = !box.box.open;
            }
        }, false);

        var markerRoot = arController.createThreeBarcodeMarker(20);
        markerRoot.add(box.box);
        arScene.scene.add(markerRoot);

        var tick = function() {
            arScene.process();

            box.box.tick();
            
            arScene.renderOn(renderer);
            requestAnimationFrame(tick);
        };

        tick();

    }});

    delete window.ARThreeOnLoad;

};

if (window.ARController && ARController.getUserMediaThreeScene) {
    ARThreeOnLoad();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

